# How to apply a partial transpose to a list of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

If I start with some 4x4 input matrix

$\rho=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$

and evolve this according to the unitary evolution operator

$U=e^{-iHt}$

where $H$ is the Hamiltonian

$H=0.03(\sigma_x\otimes\sigma_x+\sigma_y\otimes\sigma_y+\sigma_z\otimes\sigma_z)$

such that the output matrix is given by

$\rho_{out}(t)=U\rho U^\dagger$

I can plot a table of values of $\rho$ using just

```
rho={{0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}}

H=0.03(KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1],PauliMatrix[1]]
 +KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[2],PauliMatrix[2]]
 +KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[3],PauliMatrix[3]])

U[t_]=MatrixExp[-I*H*t]

rhoout[t_]=U[t].rho.U[t]

rhooutlist=Table[rhoout[t],{t,0,500}].
```

However, this output is not a list of matrices, but one matrix with a list of values for each element. The next thing I want to do is to take the partial transpose of each output matrix, probably using the method in [How does one transpose in place the off-diagonal 16 x 16 blocks of a 32 x 32 matrix?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130161/how-does-one-transpose-in-place-the-off-diagonal-16-x-16-blocks-of-a-32-x-32-mat).

I'm not sure whether the best way would be to somehow convert the output to a list of matrices or whether to use a different method for the partial trace.

Comment: "However, this output is not a list of matrices, but one matrix with a list of values for each element. " I don't get it. `rhooutlist` is a list containing 501 $4 \times 4$ matrices.

Comment: Well I mean if I try to do some operation, for example

    rhoout.ConjugateTranspose[rhoout]

it sees     `rhoout`      as one matrix that is the wrong shape rather than applying this to each matrix in the list

Comment: The simplest way to deal with that would be to learn about `Map`. Define a function that processes a $4 \times 4$ matrix and `Map` it over the list `rhooutlist`.

Comment: I'm still not sure how this would apply to the operation `rhoout.ConjugateTranspose[rhoout]`. The description of how `Map` works seems to be for operations that are applied to the list, not where the list is a list of operations.

Comment: `Map[m \[Function] m.ConjugateTranspose[m], rhoout]`

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work, I get an error saying that the first two levels can't be transposed because they contain lists.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, but maybe this does what you want:

```
r1 = Map[
   m \[Function] 
    Flatten[Transpose[Partition[m, {2, 2}]], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}],
   rhooutlist
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.056507

For each matrix in the list `rhooutlist`, this swaps the upper right $2 \times 2$ block with the lower left $2 \times 2$ block.

The following does the same but is almost twice as fast:

```
r2 = Flatten[
   Transpose[
    Flatten[
     Partition[rhooutlist, {1, 2, 2}],
     {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4, 5}, {6}}
     ],
    {1, 3, 2, 4, 5}],
   {{1}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}
   ];// AbsoluteTiming // First

r1 == r2
```

> 0.028758
>
> True

And even faster is using `Compile` which enables parallelization:

```
r3 = Compile[{{m, _Complex, 2}},
      Partition[Flatten[Transpose[Partition[m, {2, 2}], {3, 1, 2, 4}]], 4],
      CompilationTarget -> "WVM",
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      Parallelization -> True
      ][rhooutlist]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

r1 == r2 == r3
```

> 0.007143
>
> True

Answer (score 1):

Henrik's answer is hardcoded for transposing specific parts only, but for anyone working with quantum mechanics it would help a lot to have a general [partial transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peres%E2%80%93Horodecki_criterion#Definition) available. Here is mine:

First I need two helper functions to map "matrix indexes" to the "indexes in the subsystems" and back:

```
indexCombinedToIndexSystems::usage = "
  indexCombinedToIndexSystems[indexCombined,systemsDimensions]

  indexCombined: index of the combined system
  systemsDimensions: list of subsystem dimensions

  automatically threads over indexCombined, if list

  Example for 3 2-state systems:
  indexSystemsToIndexCombined[6,{2,2,2}] == {1,1,0}
  ";
indexCombinedToIndexSystems[indexCombined : {__Integer}, 
   systemsDimensions : {__Integer}] :=
  indexCombinedToIndexSystems[#, systemsDimensions] & /@ indexCombined;
indexCombinedToIndexSystems[indexCombined_Integer, 
   systemsDimensions : {__Integer}] := Module[
   {reminder = indexCombined - 1, indexSystem, indexSystems},
   indexSystems = Table[
     {indexSystem, reminder} = QuotientRemainder[reminder, base];
     indexSystem,
     {base, Reverse@FoldList[Times][systemsDimensions[[;; -2]]]}
     ];
   Append[indexSystems, reminder] + 1
   ];
indexSystemsToIndexCombined::usage = "
  indexSystemsToIndexCombined[indexSystems, systemsDimensions]

  indexSystems: list of indexes in each system
  systemsDimensions: list of subsystem dimensions

  automatically threads over indexSystems, if list of lists

  Example for 3 2-state systems:
  indexSystemsToIndexCombined[{1,1,0},{2,2,2}] == 6
  ";
indexSystemsToIndexCombined[indexSystems : {{__Integer} ...}, 
    systemsDimensions : {__Integer}] /;
   Dimensions[indexSystems][[2]] === Length[systemsDimensions] :=
  indexSystemsToIndexCombined[#, systemsDimensions] & /@ indexSystems;
indexSystemsToIndexCombined[indexSystems : {__Integer}, 
   systemsDimensions : {__Integer}] /;
  Length[indexSystems] === Length[systemsDimensions] :=
 Total[Reverse@
     FoldList[Times][
      systemsDimensions[[;; -2]]] (indexSystems[[;; -2]] - 1)] + 
  indexSystems[[-1]]
```

These functions can be used a follows:

```
In[284]:= 
  Table[indexCombinedToIndexSystems[i, {2, 2, 2}], {i, 8}]
  indexSystemsToIndexCombined[#, {2, 2, 2}] & /@ %

Out[284]= 
  {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, 
   {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}

Out[285]= 
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

In[294]:= 
  indexCombinedToIndexSystems[Range[1, 8], {2, 2, 2}]
  indexSystemsToIndexCombined[%, {2, 2, 2}]

Out[294]= 
  {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, 
   {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}

Out[295]= 
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

Now it is easy to describe the partial transpose as it swaps the "indexes" in a subspace only:

```
partialTranspose[a_?MatrixQ, systemsDimensions : {__Integer}, 
   systemsTransposed : {___?BooleanQ}] /;
  Times @@ systemsDimensions === Length[a] :=
 Table[Module[{k, l},
   {k, l} = MapThread[
       (* Swap the indexes for transposed subsystems *)
       If[#2, Reverse@#1, #1]&,
       {  indexCombinedToIndexSystems[{i, j}, 
          systemsDimensions]\[Transpose], systemsTransposed}
       ]\[Transpose]~indexSystemsToIndexCombined~systemsDimensions;
   a[[k, l]]],
  {i, Length[a]},
  {j, Length[a]}
  ]

comb = Array[Subscript[a, #1, #2] &, {2, 2}]~KroneckerProduct~
   Array[Subscript[b, #1, #2] &, {2, 2}];
MatrixForm[comb]
```

[image: product]

```
MatrixForm@partialTranspose[comb, {2, 2}, {True, False}]
```

[image: transposed]